# How to re-render the @section in Laravel Blade template?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm new to Laravel. May I know is there a way to replace the @section without reloading the page using Laravel Blade template?
For example, I have a @section('content') showing 2 different payment methods to let the user choose. When the user choose either one, I want to replace the @section('content') with another view that let the user proceed with the payment.

```
@section('nav')
  // View that display 2 different payment methods
  // When user selects either one, replace this @section('nav') with another view
@endsection
```

Comment: @section is rendered during the page load, you cannot replace it without reloading the page, you can replace the html with javascript/ajax.

Comment: i think you can use javascript or jquery to achieve that. Like hidden the `section` and use js to show the `section` when needed.

Comment: Alright. I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: another option specific to laravel can be using Laravel Livewire. You can re-render a blade file on user interaction using Livewire package